# How to Connect local KInesis Application To localstack Kinesis Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, localstack

I am trying to connect Simple Java Application which adds some data to Kinesis Stream that is running on localStack

Below is java code

```
package org.example;

import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.*;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String localStackEndpoint = "localhost"; // LocalStack Kinesis endpoint
        String awsRegion = "us-east-1"; 
        String streamName = "test"; //stream name

        KinesisProducerConfiguration config = new KinesisProducerConfiguration()
                .setRegion(awsRegion)
                .setKinesisEndpoint(localStackEndpoint)
                .setKinesisPort(4566);

        KinesisProducer kinesisProducer = new KinesisProducer(config);

        String data = "Sample data to put into Kinesis stream";
        String partitionKey = "partition-key-78";

        UserRecord userRecord = new UserRecord(streamName, partitionKey, ByteBuffer.wrap(data.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        ListenableFuture<UserRecordResult> userRecordResultListenableFuture = kinesisProducer.addUserRecord(userRecord);

        while (!userRecordResultListenableFuture.isDone()) {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }

        UserRecordResult userRecordResult;
        try {
            userRecordResult = userRecordResultListenableFuture.get();
            if (userRecordResult.isSuccessful()) {
                System.out.println("Record put into Kinesis stream successfully.");
                System.out.println("Sequence Number: " + userRecordResult.getSequenceNumber());
            } else {
                System.err.println("Failed to put the record into Kinesis stream.");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            kinesisProducer.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting the below error
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.UserRecordFailedException
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:592)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:551)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:111)
at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:35)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.UserRecordFailedException
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer$MessageHandler.onPutRecordResult(KinesisProducer.java:239)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer$MessageHandler.access$100(KinesisProducer.java:164)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.KinesisProducer$MessageHandler$1.run(KinesisProducer.java:171)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Is there anything which I am missing in the code? Below is my localstack docker container
[image]

Comment: I figured out a solution. I was missing to pass the STS endpoint and STS port as a config to Kinesis Producer. Below is the updated Kinesis Producer config
KinesisProducerConfiguration config = new KinesisProducerConfiguration()
                .setKinesisEndpoint("localhost")
                .setKinesisPort(4566)
                .setStsEndpoint("localhost")
                .setStsPort(4566)
                .setVerifyCertificate(false)
                .setMaxConnections(1)
                .setRequestTimeout(60000)
                .setRegion(awsRegion);